# Legal recognition of polygamy around the world?

Tags: marriage, civil-rights

Are you aware of any country of the world in which polygamy (with no restrictions over the gender of the involved people) is legally recognized or at least there is some battle for it?

Comment: "or at least there is some battle for it" Political efforts to change the law are beyond the scope of Law.SE, unless you mean lawsuits alleging what is colorably a right under existing law.

Answer (score 4):

Nowhere is this legal. Polygamy is legal in 58 countries, [polyandry](https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-where-polygamy-is-legal) is possibly legal in Sri Lanka and [Bhutan](http://www.bhutanwatch.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/G-Rizal.pdf). Neither country recognizes [same-sex marriage](https://www.pewresearch.org/religion/fact-sheet/gay-marriage-around-the-world/), ruling out a marriage between three women. The [law of Bhutan](https://www.nationalcouncil.bt/assets/uploads/docs/acts/2017/Marriage-Act-of-Bhutan-1980_Eng.pdf) is clear on the requirement of male-female mixing, only allowing marriage between 1 man and 1 woman at a time.
In Sri Lanka, the [Kandyan Marriage and Divorce Act](http://www.commonlii.org/lk/legis/consol_act/mad132209.pdf) also allows multiple husbands for a woman, but only for Kandyans (Buddhist from the former provinces of the Kandyan Kingdom).